# How to use a UIAlertController in MVVM?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uialertcontroller

I have a VC with code to show an alert:

```
func showMessage() {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "TEST",
                                      message: self.loginViewModel.errorText,
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
    present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and I have this login logic in my viewModel which needs to trigger this function:

```
func submitLoginRequest(userLogin: String, loginPassword: String, loginSecret: String, deviceToken: String) {
        let userLogin = UserServices.init()
        manager.userServicesApiRequest(url: Endpoints.login, request: userLogin) { (data, error) in
            if let data = data {
                let status = data["status"].stringValue
                if status == "success" {
                    guard let userObject = UserProfileModel.init(data) else { return }
                    let encodedUserObject: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userObject)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedUserObject, forKey: "userProfile")
                    print("Login Succeeded")                        self.coordinatorDelegate?.loginViewModelDidLogin(viewModel: self)
                } else {
                    self.errorText = data["reason"].stringValue
                    // here is where the controller needs calling!
                }
            }
```

I wanted to know how i should have them interact correctly to trigger the VC when the VM case is hit?

Comment: At that point you should call something like `self.coordinatorDelegate?.loginViewModelDidFailToLogin()` and have it handle it.

Comment: that was my thought, however how do i then get the coordinator to access / handle the viewcontroller? another delegate?

Comment: Personnally, I think MVVM is a waste of time on iOS unless you are using a data binding framework. MVVM comes from Windows where there is an in-built data binding capability via WPF.  Really, your view model shouldn't be performing the login anyway, that is the responsibility of the model,  the View Model merely exposes the relevant properties of the model to enable the data binding. The view coordinator needs to advise the view (which in the case of iOS is going to be a UIViewController) of the failed login which can display the alert. And yes, this would be through delegation.

Comment: i do have rxSwift but am new to it so not always utilising it. so the login function should be called inside the model class? and the VC handles the alert controller which triggers via delegate?

Comment: @Paulw11 Models never have business logic inside them how come it will call an API ?

Comment: You can have an API object; it models/abstracts your API. It isn’t “business logic” but it does have code to implement an adapter pattern between your data model and the network api.